# Elasticsearch: simple query string with latin characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using a simple query string over the following text:

> Jiboia de três metros é capturada em avenida de Governador

**Obs**: This is the content of my message field

My query string (no results)

```
"simple_query_string":{
     "query":"tr\u00eas",
     "fields":["message","author.name","author.id"],
     "default_operator":"AND"
}
```

My query string (1 result)

```
"simple_query_string":{
     "query":"Jiboia",
     "fields":["message","author.name","author.id"],
     "default_operator":"AND"
}
```

Have a trick for latin characters?

My mapping:

```html
{"mentions-2016.02.26":{"aliases":{"mentions_ro":{},"mentions_rw":{}},"mappings":{"mention":{"dynamic_templates":[{"analyzer":{"mapping":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","store":"no"},"match":"*","match_mapping_type":"string"}}],"date_detection":false,"properties":{"analytics":{"properties":{"collect_delay":{"type":"long"},"number_of_replies":{"type":"long"},"twitter_reach":{"type":"long"},"youtube_views":{"type":"long"}}},"author":{"properties":{"gender":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"id":{"type":"string"},"locale":{"properties":{"area":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"country":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}},"name":{"type":"string"},"platform_id":{"type":"long"}}},"created_at":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"},"elastic_date":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"},"id":{"type":"long"},"items_batch_created":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"},"message":{"type":"string"},"metadata":{"properties":{"event":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"timestamp":{"type":"long"}}},"monitoring":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"long"},"owner":{"properties":{"email":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"id":{"type":"long"},"plan":{"properties":{"active":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"name":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"paid":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}}}}}},"parent_id":{"type":"long"},"published_at":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"},"raw_content":{"properties":{"actor_link":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"aid":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"atom_content":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"attachment_content":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"attachment_image":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"attachment_text":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"attachment_url":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"attribution":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"author":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"author_name":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"author_uri":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"can_comment":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"caption":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"cast":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"category":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"channellink":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"channeltitle":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"comment_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"comment_info":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"comment_real_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"comments":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"content":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"created_at":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"created_time":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"createdat":{"type":"long"},"date_timestamp":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"dateuploaded":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"description":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"displayName":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"download":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"downloadurl":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"duration":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"embed":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"embed_privacy":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"farm":{"type":"long"},"firstname":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"flickrid":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"fonte_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"format":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"fotoPai":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"from_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"from_name":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"from_user":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"from_user_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"from_user_profile_image_url":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"gdcomments":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"gender":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"guid":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"height":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"icon":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"idComment":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"idVideo":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"id_externo":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"idexterno":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"image":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"imagem":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"impactoyoutube":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"inReplyTo":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"url":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}},"in_reply_to_screen_name":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"in_reply_to_status_id":{"type":"long"},"incontest":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"isPicture":{"type":"boolean"},"is_hd":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"is_private":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"is_transcoding":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"iso_language_code":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"klout":{"type":"long"},"language":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"like_info":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"likes":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"link":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"link_related":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"link_self":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"location":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"mediacategory":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"mediacontent":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"mediadescription":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"mediakeywords":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"mediaplayer":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"mediathumbnail":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"mediatitle":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"message":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"modified_date":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"monitoramento_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"name":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"note_count":{"type":"long"},"number_of_comments":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"number_of_likes":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"number_of_plays":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"owner":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"parent_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"permalink":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"photo":{"properties":{"default":{"type":"boolean"},"prefix":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"suffix":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}},"picture":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"post_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"privacy":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"profile_image_url":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"profile_picture":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"pubdate":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"publicado":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"published":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"realname":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"removido":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"retroactive":{"type":"boolean"},"secret":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"secretkey":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"server":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"share_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"slide_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"slideshowembedurl":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"slideshowtype":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"source":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"src_big":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"status":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"summary":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"t_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"tags":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"text":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"texto":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"thumbnail":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"thumbnails":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"thumbnailsize":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"thumbnailsmallurl":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"thumbnailurl":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"thumbnailxlargeurl":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"thumbnailxxlargeurl":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"tip_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"title":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"to":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"to_user":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"to_user_id":{"type":"long"},"tumblr_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"tweet_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"type":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"update_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"updated":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"updatedVideo":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"updated_time":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"upload_date":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"url":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"urls":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"user_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"user_url":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"userimageurl":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"username":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"userurl":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"veioDoAlbum":{"type":"boolean"},"video":{"type":"long"},"vimeo_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"wall_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"width":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"ytduration":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}},"raw_content_hash":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"search":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"long"},"social_network":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"type":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"type_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}},"sentiment":{"properties":{"automatic":{"properties":{"active":{"type":"long"},"precision":{"type":"long"},"value":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}},"value":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}},"tag":{"properties":{"count":{"type":"long"},"ids":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}},"title":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"type":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"updated_at":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"},"words":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}}},"settings":{"index":{"refresh_interval":"2s","number_of_shards":"7","gc_deletes":"1814400","creation_date":"1456497520658","number_of_replicas":"2","version":{"created":"1050299"},"uuid":"sp4CJpxMRf-_z0bUtHTrjA"}},"warmers":{}}}
```

Comment: Can you share your document mapping and eventually the index settings?

Comment: you should have a look at unicode character folding ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/character-folding.html#character-folding and language analyzers https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html

Comment: this works out of the box both for `tr\u00eas` and `três`, no reason it should not work. So probably you're doing some preprocessing before saving or you have something set in your mappings/configs you should share with us or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I edit and put my mapping on post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Im using javascript atob function to decode the message after index it on elastic.
The atob function does not work well with my latin characters and break it.
I change atob for the native Buffer class on node js.

> Obs: The default analizer work perfect with latin chars!

Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need let elasticsearch know how handle your characters.
I did an example using an custom tokenizer like this:

```
curl -XPOST "http://192.168.99.100:9200/my_type/my_type/my_type" -d'
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
        },  
        "analysis" : {
            "filter" : {
                "custom_filter" : {
                    "type" : "word_delimiter",
                    "type_table": ["ê => ALPHA", "Ê => ALPHA"]
                }   
            },
            "analyzer" : {
                "custom_analyzer" : {
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "filter" : ["lowercase", "custom_filter"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "my_type" : {
            "properties" : {
                "msg" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "analyzer" : "custom_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I just created an analyzer using a tokenizer that know that ê and Ê need to be interpreted as characters.

after that i just do a search in my msg field

```
curl -XPOST "http://192.168.99.100:9200/my_type/my_type/my_type/my_type" -d'
{
    "msg":"três"
}'
```

And will work :D

Comment: you don't need all of that, try removing the `analyzer` from your mapping and it should still work.

Comment: @WaldemarNeto No `analyzer` doesn't mean `not_analyzed` just that the field will be using the default (e.g. `standard`) analyzer

Comment: I'm not saying you should use `not_analyzed`, I said you should remove the `analyzer` from your mapping, then ES would use the default analyzer

Comment: default analyzer does not support special characters